# PHP Warning: unable to load dynamic library php_pdo_sqlite.dll & php_sqlite3.dll

Tags: php, php-7.1

I have been using php 7.1 for a while on mac, after trying to install composer I have got the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_sqlite3.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_sqlite3.dll, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_sqlite3.dll in Unknown on line 0
```

In the /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303 directory there are only two files:
- opache.so
- xdebug.so

I have found a couple of threads which relate to this and after checking the php ini and running phpinfo() can't find a way forward with resolving this issue.

tried running

```
php -i | grep ini

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_pdo_sqlite.dll in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_sqlite3.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_sqlite3.dll, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_sqlite3.dll in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
Supported handlers => ndbm cdb cdb_make inifile flatfile 
init_command_executed_count => 0
init_command_failed_count => 0
com_init_db => 0
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
open sourced by => Epinions.com
```

[edit]

In the ini file all references to DLL files are commented out, all references to sqlite are commented out.

Can anyone provide me with some more information on how to resolve this?

I am using PHP 7.1 and using a Mac with Mojave.

Comment: Don't put lines referencing DLL files in your configuration. They're for Windows.

Comment: I've looked in the php ini and can't find a reference to these. How do I change the config?

Comment: try running "php -i | grep ini", as you might have more ini files

Comment: tried this and there is only one version installed.